# pg_restore with ssl parameters - how to specify parameters right way?

Tags: ssl, postgresql, database-restore

I have PostgreSQL 11 server with ssl-only connections (it's "Managed PostgreSQL" service by my cloud provider)

In documentation `psql` connection to this server should be like this:

```
psql "host=xxx.mdb.yandexcloud.net \
      port=6432 \
      sslmode=verify-full \
      dbname=<database> \
      user=<user>\
      target_session_attrs=read-write"
```

With this command I'm able to connect to server succesfully. So, next step is to restore my database from backup to that server.

Previously I used this command to restore backup to my old postgreSQL server:

```
pg_restore -d <database> -O -c -v -x <file>.dump
```

So, I tried to do this:

```
pg_restore "host=xxx.mdb.yandexcloud.net \
      port=6432 \
      sslmode=verify-full \
      dbname=<database> \
      user=<user>\
      target_session_attrs=read-write" -d <database> -O -c -v -x <file>.dump
```

and got this error:

```
pg_restore: too many command-line arguments (first is "<file>.dump")
Try "pg_restore --help" for more information.
```

So all I need it to set `pg_restore` right way, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
PGTARGETSESSIONATTRS=read-write PGSSLMODE=verify-full pg_restore -Fd \
-v -h <host(s)> -p6432 -U<user> -d <db> --single-transaction --no-privileges <backup folder>
```

But ensure (if you do run this from outside of YandexCloud) that current master host has public IP assigned.